# Using DSLR Controller for a Secondary Display

Tags: java, android, latency, photography

I am trying to create a low latency method to use an android device as a secondary display for a PC. So far all I have found has been either wireless streaming, or a slow usb connection (i.e. using iDisplay).
However, I found a DSLR camera contoller app (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dslr.dashboard/) that is able to stream a live feed of the camera to an android display via USB. Would it be possible to edit the source code of this application so it can read the video output of PC via USB? If so, how would you go about this? Do you think that this would be a low latency alternative?

Thank you!

Comment: I found the source code on github at https://github.com/hubaiz/DslrDashboard/tree/master/DslrDashboard for all who are curious

Comment: hi, did you have any success? i also need a low latency bi-directional com link between my pc app and android slave app. the app works now via wifi but the latency is too slow (about 300mS), i'm looking to get it down to 10mS or so.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of fantasy in your question. Have you ever seen a PC outputting data from one of its USB ports to another device? How are you supposed to do that? With a plain male-to-male USB cable, in case you find one? Sorry but things don't go that way. To transfer data (files, or a network) via USB between two computers you'd need some propietary/specific software. Of course, once you have acomplished that is technically possible to transfer files with the screen content. Buy you'd need to develop a software that would capture the computer screen, compress it in real time, and send it through USB with enough low latency to be usable. That's going to be resource intensive.

A better, easier approach would be, maybe, using some sort of remote desktop or VNC on the Android machine, with the computer acting as a server. At least far more feasible than trying to implement a similar protocol by yourself.

Sorry but what you are trying to achieve is flawed from the beginning.